# Java Heap Space Exception, with big ammount of data, any solution?

Tags: java, oracle, ms-access, heap-memory

I've a litle big problem with java heap memory
I'm trying to migrate from oracle database 11g to access file 2007

This is not a problem below 65.000 records, now from there...
The aplication is throwing java heap exception, the memory consumption is raising over 600m and the CPU usage over 50% until the exeption.

As far as i know the rset.next() don't get all data (over 50 colums x +65000 row), but some records x time
i've try to set fetch size too, nothing happened

```
rset.setFetchSize(1000);
```

i've erase my code and show a output, same error

```
while (rset.next()) {
 if (cont % 5000 == 0) {
     System.out.println(cont + " proccesed and counting ...");
 }
}
```

please don't give me the answer of using -xm(s, x)512, 1024, etc...
this could solved, not in my particulary case (i've tryied to set this even higher xD, nothing happend, i got the same exception at 65.000 records too)

Is there any other options i could try??, 
meaby changing some driver configurations or string conections ??
please help

sorry aboubt my english

this is my connection:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + getServer() + ":1521:orcl", getUser(), getPassword());
                this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

Comment: can we see your error message?

Comment: What's the MS-ACCESS tag doing on this question? I see nothing in it about Access or the Jet/ACE database engine.

Comment: yes, i drop the code for this question, only doing the oracle query, for you to know that is not a access problem connection

Comment: Is there any way that you could split your result set so you don't return so many records all at once?

Comment: yeah i thought that too, but meaby i'would create a temp table to do so, i need this generate a MSAccess database in 1 click for my clients to download it. but how to do that ?? thx for all the answers

Comment: You're mentioning Access in the comments, but I still don't see anything at all about Access in your actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are using a Scrollable ResultSet and that is going to use more memory.

Comment: @ErVeY: you should use `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` instead of `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` if you are processing the resultset row by row. I think the implementation for `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` is to cache the rows as they are fetched, leading to the memory overflow (since all Oracle cursor are forward-only on the database side, the client has to implement the scrollable feature through client-side cache)

Comment: Thx Vincent i'll try that, i've been disconnected of the world since i did this question so i could't follow the theards, sorry about that

Comment: i've switched to the type_forward_only and now works fine at the moment thx to Vincent and JZD for the answer =D